# How to get the co-ordinates of the line with openCv in python

Tags: python, opencv, houghlines

I am trying to get the actual coordinates of the lines after applying *hough* line method in **OpenCV** for detecting lines. By co-ordinates, I meant the endpoints of lines. 
This is the code I have used for detecting lines in opencv -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('image_name.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength=100,maxLineGap=10)
for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What do you mean by the coordinates of the line?  Just the end points or all the pixels along the line?  Please be more specific. Please show your current code. Please read "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  See the documentation at https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

Comment: @fmw42 sorry for the ambiguity, I edited it

Comment: x1,y1 and x2,y2 are the end point coordinates. What is wrong with that? Can you post your input and output images?